# pandas groupby group and subgroup level analysis

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

On a multi-column **groupby** object, how do I access only the outer column? For e.g. below, i can access the inner column (entertainment content) through: `df.get_group(('media', 'entertainment content'))` command, I desire to be able to also access something like: df.get_group(('media')) but it throws an error: **"ValueError: must supply a tuple to get_group with multiple grouping keys"**

```
[('media', 'entertainment content'),('media', 'internet media')]

df.get_group(('media', 'entertainment content'))
                                     lasts      vol        prev ticker
industry sub_industry                                                 
media    entertainment content  379.200012  1828139  354.000000  suntv
         entertainment content  420.049988  2675741  404.600006      z

temp.get_group(('media'))
ValueError: must supply a tuple to get_group with multiple grouping keys
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to access 'media', you don't need the extra set of parentheses when you call `get_group`. So it'd just be `get_group('media')`.

If you wanted to retrieve multiple groups, that's when you would use an extra set of parentheses, which would create the tuple. For instance: `get_group(('media','pizza'))`

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do something similar (creating columns for each subgroups). But, as far as I know, the approach below suited me and would help you as well. I tried to find the solution in the cookbook pandas documentation has provided, but it didn't help. Here is the way, I would suggest,

`grp = df.groupby('industry', 'sub_industry')
values = []`

`for sub_ind in (df.sub_industry.unique()):
    values.append(grp.get_group(('media', sub_ind)))`

Answer (score 0):

As with `pandas.get_group` it looks like it is not possible to access a single key after grouping by more than one key, I suggest the following alternative method.

Generating the data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rand = np.random.RandomState(1)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 'bar'] * 12,
               'B': rand.randn(24),
               'C': rand.randint(0, 20, 24),
               'D': ['aaa','bbb','ccc'] * 8})
```

Grouping by multiple keys ('A' and 'D') and using `pandas.ngroup` to assign a group number, storing it in a new column:

```
df["grouping_AandD"] = df.groupby(["A", "D"]).ngroup()
```

Using the just created column to display all combinations in a loop but show only those containing the 'wanted key' ('foo' in this case):

```
wanted_key = "foo"
for i in range(0, df.grouping_AandD.nunique()):
    grouped_df = df[df.grouping_AandD == i]
    if (grouped_df.A.all() == wanted_key):
        print(grouped_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code is not working is beacuse you created a group with multiple keys but when calling the get_group method you are using just one key (industry) which is 'media'. @Cashe Staheli mentioned in second option what you need to do as follows

`get_group(('value1','value2'))`

Answer (score -2):

Just do what the error message says and use a tuple:

```
temp.get_group(('media',))
```

Note the trailing comma.

Comment: hi. I tried just that, it give me the below error
temp.get_group(('media',))
ValueError: must supply a a same-length tuple to get_group with multiple grouping keys

Comment: OP's problem wasn't that he/she was not attempting to use a tuple, but that he/she did not recognize that `(x)` is not a tuple in Python, while `(x,)` is.